# FileNotFoundException when accessing a resource file after deploy to tomcat

Tags: java, maven, resources, tomcat8

I got two maven projects:

1. A JAR with a resource file accessed from its code
2. A WAR that has a RESTful service that uses the JAR

When the JAR unit tests run, it is able to access the resource file.

After deploying to tomcat, the access to the resource file fails with FileNotFoundException

I tried both these lines but the same results:

```
File file = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("file.xml").getFile());
```

And

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/file.xml").getFile());
```

When debugging, I found the value of `file` is as following:

```
file:/usr/share/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/com.projectgroup.projectname-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/file.xml
```

I've opened the JAR at that location and found the file there. So any idea why this is happening.

Comment: File is for operating system files. Zipped inside a jar just use getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream for an InputStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `getResourceAsStream()` instead of `resource.getFile()`

Another way to get your xml file loaded in your classpath is by using the Spring Framework as below:

```
PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
resolver.getResources("classpath*:your/package/**/file.xml");
```

Comment: couldn't find `resource.getInputStream` but I've used `getClass().getResourceAsStream` instead. I still don't understand why the `getFile` didn't work. Thanks anyway

Comment: resource.getInputStream() is an error, I wanted to write getResourceAsStream(). I will correct the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your file has to be in the classpath in the war file, is it being packed into the war as part of the build process?

Comment: I am using maven, also I made sure the file is packed into the JAR

Comment: A clarification, I resource file is in a JAR that is a dependency for the main WAR

Comment: if you are using maven try building the war file with the file you are trying to access in the main/resources directory